# Running a function by typing in URL

Tags: php, url

I have searched all over the internet to run a function from URL and found out it is not possible.

I am asking if there is another way to do this. I will explain below what I am trying to achieve.

On my website I have several functions that when a hyperlink is clicked on that cracks.php page, the main content changes accordingly. Now I want to direct people from a single URL to that cracks.php page with the function already called.
Example  - www.example.com/cracks.php?AC ( which will call a function named AC and the content changes before the page loads)

Ive found this method below, but couldnt get it to work.

```
if(document.location.search == '?AC')  
{  
    AC();  
}
```

Sorry for the messy code on the website. Thanks for reading, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that in a `window.onload` or some sort of loader making sure the `DOM` is `ready`?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `www.example.com/cracks.php?do=AC` and then get `do` with `$doMethod = $_GET['do'];`. What you then do is, use a `switch` function or a few `if`s to check and execute when e.g. `$doMethod` equals `AC`.

Like this:

```
$doMethod = $_GET['do'];
switch($doMethod)
{
    case "AC":
        //some random stuff to do
        break;
    case "BD":
        //some random stuff to do
        break;
    case "XY":
        //some random stuff to do
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I also Tried your method but nothing happened. I tried both in internal(in the head) and in external. Any help, maybe im missing something

Comment: Are you aware that my solution is coded in `PHP` and not `JavaScript` ...? Since you tagged it as `PHP` I gave the answer in that language.

Comment: Oh, OK sorry, my fault then :D . Now that we started on php I might keep using it. Can I call a javascript function from php ? If no, a javascript method would be really appreciated.I am writing the same messages to both of you as I am not sure which method I am going to use.

Comment: Thats cool. No, you can't call JS from PHP or visa-versa. They are completely independent. PHP runs on the server and treats JS as characters (same as text) and send it all through to the client where JS lives. By the time JS is activated, the PHP code has been processed and gone. (Not visible to JS) But for your problem, this PHP solution is a good way to go. http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: Thanks for helping but solved it by using a Javascript method. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

That depends if you need to do that dynamically or you can do it hard coded. Because that hard coded is too simple (with if's and switches), what you have to do is:

```
$functionsList = Array('func1', 'func2');


function func1(){
    echo '1';
}

function func2(){
    echo '2';
}

if (function_exists($_GET['f']) and in_array($_GET['f'], $functionsList)){
    call_user_func($_GET['f']);
}
```

Then call **your_file_name.php?f=func1** and **your_file_name.php?f=func2** and you'll see different outputs.

Comment: Tried your method but nothing happened. I tried both in internal(in the head) and in external.  Any help, maybe im missing something

Comment: That's strange because I tried it in my computer and it worked. Did you run this code and it didn't worked? Or have you changed it? If so, be sure the funcion exists and it's listed in the `Array` **$functionsList**.  _PS:_ This is PHP, as @Nideo code,  not JavaScript. You must be aware of that. :)

Comment: Oh, OK sorry, my fault then :D . Now that we started on php I might keep using it. Can I call a javascript function from php ? If no, a javascript method would be really appreciated. I am writing the same messages to both of you as I am not sure which method I am going to use.

Comment: Directily no. However you can print with PHP some JavasSript that will call the JavaScript function.

Comment: Is your method possible with Javascript ? If no, what should I use to print Javascript that will call the functions ?

Comment: It is possible, but not the way I'm doing Someone with more experience of JavaScript would know how to do it, I can't. ;)

Comment: OK, then I should re post the question with a javascript tag. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mark Koopman I managed to use his Javascript method and it worked like I wanted.

So heres the method in Javascript:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function handleOnload()
            {
                if(location.search == "?AC")
                   alert("the query string is " + location.search);
            }

            window.onload=handleOnload;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```